# New SQL Server - help with request of requirements for installing server w/SQl Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, acquisition

So my employer has asked me to come up with list of "requirements" to put in a SQL Server. Just very general, however I am pretty inexperienced at such a thing.

So my list looks like:

- SERVER
- SQL SERVER ENTERPRISE EDITION
- ADDITIONAL SOFTWARE

and that is about it. I know very little about the make up of servers, so I have no idea what would be applicable (just in general not super specific) or what would meet the  requirements of SQL Server? Can someone please provide additional help with this one please

ADDITIONAL SOFTWARE: are there typical software packages that one should acquire when trying to accomplish this?

Appreciate the advice/guidance greatly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS (at least specify 32bit or 64bit)

SERVER - do you have to specify a hardware configuration?
(this can be a separate topic alone!) Consult with the white papers

Availability - is it just a standalone server? Do you need to do logshipping and/or DB mirroring?

SECURITY - you need this section, trust me!

BACKUP

etc
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143516(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would also check exactly which version of SQL Server you need (Enterprise, Standard etc) and what licensing model you want to use, as the cost variation is enormous.

As DimitryK said, look at your backup strategy too, as this could also involve additional hardware - whether that be another server, replication or tape etc